# How can I convert a Clojure namespace to a string?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to pretty print a list of namespaces:

```
(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println x))
```

This prints each namespace as `#<Namespace xxxxx>`. I would like to get each namespace as `xxxxx`  (that is without the `#<Namespace>`. I tried to `(name x)`, `(symbol x)` but I get `ClassCastException clojure.lang.Namespace cannnot be cast to java.lang.Named`, etc.

```
(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println (name x)))
(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println (str x)))
(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println (namespace x)))
```

How can I get the namespace as a string?

Comment: I realized that actually `(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println (str x)))` does work, I did have a typo when I tried. But `ns-name` as pointed in the answers is the function to use, better than `str`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ns-name`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns-name):

```
(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println (ns-name x)))
```

Note that `ns-name` gives you a symbol. So if you want a string just use `(str (ns-name ns))`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ns-name` function:

```
(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println (ns-name x)))
```

[Namespace function docs can be found here](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-name)

Best of luck.